# Как кастомизировать сообщение при success ajax-формы в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

При успешной отправке формы методом AJAX, выводится сообщение "Спасибо! Ваша заявка принята!".

Как можно его изменить?

Поиск по БД и файлам результата не принес.

Пытался это сделать при помощи файла result_modifier.php, размещенного в корне папки шаблона компонента:

```
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true) die();
if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
  $arResult["FORM_NOTE"] = "Мой кастомный текст";
}
$component = $this->__component;
$component->setResultCacheKeys(array("KEY_ARRAY_RESULT"));
```

Результат не поменялся.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

```
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/core/core_date.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/core/core_admin.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/utils.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/admin_tools.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/popup_menu.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/admin_search.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/hot_keys.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://site.com.ua/bitrix/js/main/public_tools.js
```

Comment: Уточните url, на который "уходит" ajax-запрос

Comment: Я не могу понять сам, в консоли их несколько. Приложил.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Вопрос закрыт. Заменил в /form.result.view/.default/template.php